# How to create sequence of date for different calendars(365 days) in R?

Tags: r, netcdf

I have .nc data file which contains daily temperature data for complete period in a single column.Time variable have 365 days calendar(no-leap year). I want to calculate monthly/ annually mean/max/min values.How to use as.date for 365 days calander?

```
d<- seq(as.Date("2071-01-01"), as.Date("2099-12-31"),1)
```

The above code create the sequence but it includes the leap year also.

Comment: I think you need to extract the 'year' from the 'd' and then use as grouping variable. i.e. `library(dplyr);data.frame(d) %>% group_by(year = format(d, "%Y")) %>% summarise(min = min(d), max = max(d))`

Comment: d is sequence of dates not data series. i want to calculate annually min/max of my data using the "d".

Comment: I don't know what you have it there, so, use the group by with the `format` of `%Y%` and then get the min, max of the other variable

Comment: What kind of person does not record or predict temperature for 29th February?

Answer (score 2):

I'am not sure if it is the nicest way of doing it. I would remove all 29th of february's from the sequence.

```
d <- d[!grepl(x = d, pattern = "-02-29$")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you want to remove all the leap years or remove just the feb 29s

```
x<-seq(as.Date("2011-01-01"),as.Date("2016-03-01"),by="day")
is.leapyear=function(year) return(((year %% 4 == 0) & (year %% 100 != 0)) | (year %% 400 == 0))
#remove all dates in leap years
x[!is.leapyear(as.integer(format(x, "%Y")))]

#remove all feb 29s
x[format(x,"%m-%d") != "02-29"]
```

Comment: hello waterling, in second line "(year %% 100 != 0)" ,what is the need of this?